# Facebook Login and CSRF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, facebook-login

I've done a fair amount of research on my problem to no avail hence why I turn to the great people at stackoverflow :)

Alright, I followed Ryan Bates' tutorial on Facebook login but it seems like Facebook has changed quite a bit in the two years since the tutorial was made. I've struggled to get Facebook to accept localhost:3000/ as an App Domain. What I ended up doing is setting the Website URL and App Domain to my staging Heroku app and in Advanced/Valid OAuth redirect URIs I put in localhost:3000/

Ok here's the problem. When I go to localhost:3000/auth/facebook, I get the following error:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError at /auth/facebook/callback
csrf_detected | CSRF detected
OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint#raise_out!
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb, line 25
```

However, when I go back to my website, I'm actually logged in. Weird. I should also add that I'm using my developer account to login. Anyway here's my code:

sessions_controller.rb

```
def facebook_login
  if request.env['omniauth.auth']
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokenable

  has_many :events

  has_secure_password

  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, format: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.oauth_token.nil? }

  def to_param
   token
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = auth.credentials.token
      user.password_confirmation = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#facebook_login'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
end
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get facebook to accept localhost, use `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

To stifle the CSRF error (allow CSRF) in a particular controller,

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token!
```

This should solve 90% of your problems.

Comment: Ok so it actually works on heroku so I suppose that's what counts the most but it should work locally. The first part worked fabulously, thanks. The second part wouldn't work. I tried to put it in application controller for good measure and it didn't work there either.

Comment: Do you still get a CSRF error, or is there a new problem? Can you post the trace of this error?